# Getting using the list with my random numbers

Tags: python, list, random

I have been trying to use lists so I can separate my integers into something organized (which lists are made to do, right?). Making these integers as random numbers are also makes this a little more confusing. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

first_list = []
for first_num in range(5):
    first_list = (random.randint(1,9))
    print ("First List",first_list)
for x in range(5):
    num_two = random.randint(2,8)
    print ("Second List",num_two)
```

My display is random numbers going down with my printed First List/Second List connected to every number.

```
First List:8
First List 3
etc.
Second List:3
Second List 7
etc.
```

Second part of my assignment is to use to compare elements in the two lists in pairs, i.e., compare the first elements in both lists, compare the second elements in the both lists which has to show the larger number in each comparison. I just wanted to show  what the conclusion is as to why I need help from you all in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I *think* you need to learn about `.append`ing to a list.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Make two list, add random numbers to each one, and [iterate over both list in parallel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) comparing their _i-th_ elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor/teacher/whoever is testing your knowledge of the list.append() method and the zip() method.

list.append() adds an element to a list. zip() yields an object that allows for iterating through multiple iterables at the same time.

read the python docs.

https://docs.python.org/3/

```
import random

first_list = []
second_list = []
for x in range(5):
    first_list.append(random.randint(1,9))
for y in range(5):
    second_list.append(random.randint(1,9))
print('First List:\n')
for num in first_list:
    print(str(num)+',\n')
print('Second List:\n')
for num in second_list:
    print(str(num)+',\n')
both_lists = zip(first_list, second_list)
for first, second in both_lists:
    if first > second:
        print('First is greater: ' + str(first))
    elif first < second:
        print('Second is greater: ' + str(second))
    else:
        print('First and second are equal: ' + str(first) + ', ' + str(second))
```

Martijn's answer is much more pythonic and elegant, although for printing the results, max() would need to be extended with a custom function to pass to map(), but I'm assuming that you don't understand list comprehension. This is the beginner's answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering! My professor has only shown us the append, not the zip. I am very curious about "The Python Docs" and will have to read it. I feel like the powerpoints arent helping me and the textbook is copied onto a powerpoint so....yeah. You and Marjin have pushed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, May be you are looking for something like this?

```
import random

first_list = []
Second_list=[]
for first_num in range(5):
    first_list.append(random.randint(1,9))

for x in range(5):
    Second_list.append(random.randint(2,8))

print([max(i) for i in zip(first_list,Second_list)])
```

You can also try :

```
print(list(map(max,zip(first_list,Second_list))))
```

Shorter version of your code:

```
import random
first_list = [random.randint(1,9) for first_num in range(5)]
Second_list=[random.randint(2,8) for x in range(5)]
print(list(map(max,zip(first_list,Second_list))))
```

Comment: I am sorry about the confusing question but you and John are what I want! Thank you!